# use object created in class constructor in class methods

Tags: php, oop, syntax

Is it possible to use an object that was created during a class' construction within the member methods of that class?

Ex

```
<?php
include ('AClass.php');

class Auto_Cart {
    function Auto_Cart() {
       $aclass = new AClass();
    }

    function DoSomething() {
       $aclass->amemberfunction();   

    }
}
?>
```

When I call DoSomething, it should call aclass->amemberfunction()

I think my syntax is wrong but maybe this just isn't possible. Can you help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: As a side note, it seems you are using PHP 4 ; that version is not maintained anymore (not even security fixes) ; if you can, it would be better switching to PHP 5.x  -- if you are not already running PHP 4 code on PHP 5, which is fine too ^^

Comment: I hear you friend :-) my company is waiting to upgrade because they're worried their legacy code won't work on a php5 server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to store the instance of `AClass` as a member variable (aka "property") of the instance of `Auto_Cart`.

Assuming PHP4 by the style of your constructor

```
class Auto_Cart
{
    /** @var $aclass AClass */
    var $aclass;

    function Auto_Cart()
    {
       $this->aclass = new AClass();
    }

    function DoSomething()
    {
       $this->aclass->amemberfunction();
    }
}
```

An just as an FYI, in OOP-speak we call this **composition** - meaning one object creates and stores a reference to another object automatically or "lazily".

Answer (score 1):

You need to store a reference to the object in order to use it later, as it will be lost when the constructor function exits.  Try storing it as a member of your Auto_Cart object, like this:

```
<?php
include ('AClass.php');

class Auto_Cart {
    function Auto_Cart() {
       $this->aclass = new AClass();
    }

    function DoSomething() {
       $this->aclass->amemberfunction();   

    }
}
?>
```